# RAII function invoke

Tags: c++, lambda

Is there a class in standard library that will invoke provided function in its destructor?
Something like this

```
class Foo
{
public:
 template<typename T>
 Foo(T callback)
 {
   _callback = callback;
 }
 ~Foo()
 {
   _callback();
 }
private:
 std::function<void()> _callback;
};
auto rai = Foo([](){ cout << "dtor";});
```

Comment: Add a semicolon `;` after the string literal `"dtor"`, and replace `_callback = T` (which doesn't make sense at all as `T` is a type) with `_callback = callback`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. `std::unique_ptr` is capable, but annoying to work with in such a way. `std::shared_ptr` at least invokes deleter if managed pointer is `nullptr`. Can't think of anything else off the top of my head.

Comment: Do you wants something like [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)?

Comment: @LouisGo I want a simple class like in the example. I'm asking because std is a big thing, and I don't want to invent a new wheel if such class exists.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Make it an answer - that's the idiomatic way to do it I think.

Comment: @lorro It is? I'd be strongly surprised if I saw `std::shared_ptr` used for that. I'd much rather reinvent the wheel and write my own class.

Comment: @konradk The answer is what Yksisarvinen wrote, but note - if you're only looking for 'something to be done when leaving the scope', you might declare a struct w/dtor on-the-spot.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Seen it used all around prod codes. NB. I understand why you say, rather write a custom class for that.

Comment: Ah, I guess it might be used in some projects. I'll make it an answer then,

Comment: [`gsl::final_act`/`finally`](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-when-you-can-t-throw-an-exception).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is an experimental [`scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit)

---

example: https://godbolt.org/z/4r54GYo33

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` for that.

```
std::shared_ptr<void>(nullptr, [](void*){ std::cout << "dtor\n";});
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/zeKzda196).

`std::shared_ptr` calls deleter even if managed pointer is `nullptr`, so there's no need to use any dummy pointer in there. However, personally I'd have strong concerns agains (ab)using `std::shared_ptr` in this way and I'd probably not let it through review. It's one big gotcha (although it may become an idiom if it's used all over a project).

Answer (score 1):

for implement it, I'd suggest not use type-erased `std::function`.

here is a possible implementation

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct scope_exit{
    [[nodiscard]]
    scope_exit(F&& f):f(std::move(f)){}
    ~scope_exit(){f();}

    scope_exit(const scope_exit&)=delete;
    scope_exit& operator=(const scope_exit&)=delete;

    F f;
};
```